# I can't connect to my sybase from laravel

Tags: laravel, odbc, sybase

I am trying to connect from laravel 8 to a Sybase ASE server. I do this through odbc, but when I do it, I get the attached error. I don't understand how to change the sybase environment variables(it says so in the error). I was searching and there are some commands that use charset, but I don't know how to add charset to the environment variables of the computer, help please.

[Msg Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTlR9.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not configured your SYBASE server correctly.

You can read all information regarding the locales.dat file here :
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00965.1550/html/macconfig/X90760.htm

You can edit environment variables using the following configuration :
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32237.1550/html/rsinstall_unix/CHDCBFGC.htm

Comment: I looked this info before and i tried to do it but  i don't understand what i am doing  bad. ¿Do you can help me pls?.

Comment: I tried to do what the document says but, as I could not,
I looked for other solutions. For example, I entered git bash commands (I use windows10), but that didn't work either.